# Xamarin.forms - There was a problem while parsing the package

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2019, android-11

I am having error message when I try to install .apk file which I make in VS2019 in Xamarin.
The app works just fine when I "install" it through debug, but I can't install through .apk file.
I am using:
Android 11.0 - API 30 - Target
Android 7.0  - API 24 - Minimum
I even make another Xamarin Android project, build it and archive but I received the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

I just need to distribute the app and it solve the problem.